# Función para recorrer matriz en R

Tags: r, funciones, dataframe

Tengo un R dataframe, que llamare `surface` como este:

```
    Vto         80    85    90    95    97.5   100   102.5  105   110   115   120
1W           1W 66.32 55.52 44.80 37.29 34.23  30.68 27.06  24.15 26.55 33.70 41.41
2W           2W 58.80 49.60 41.35 35.23 32.47  29.33 26.04  23.25 23.31 26.47 33.47
3W           3W 50.67 43.43 37.62 33.11 30.78  28.06 25.16  22.65 20.51 21.97 26.39
1M           1M 46.76 40.85 36.07 31.90 29.71  27.13 24.52  22.05 19.46 20.15 22.69
2M           2M 41.38 37.20 33.55 29.97 28.08  25.95 23.85  21.80 18.91 18.30 19.08
3M           3M 38.51 35.03 31.94 28.81 27.19  25.46 23.56  21.78 18.95 17.88 18.03
6M           6M 34.47 31.96 29.61 27.23 25.97  24.66 23.35  21.95 19.32 17.45 16.71
9M           9M 32.34 30.30 28.26 26.36 25.27  24.28 23.17  22.02 19.81 17.86 16.69
1Y           1Y 30.86 29.05 27.39 25.63 24.67  23.76 22.88  21.88 19.99 18.24 17.08
18M         18M 28.90 27.50 26.01 24.65 23.99  23.25 22.53  21.76 20.31 18.99 17.91
2Y           2Y 27.82 26.51 25.18 24.03 23.48  22.84 22.20  21.61 20.51 19.44 18.52
```

Y necesito una función que dados ciertos parámetros `search(vto,k, sp, surface)` me entregue una entrada de dicha matriz. Lo explico de la siguiente manera:

1. La función debe calcular el cociente entre `k` y `sp` `mn = k/sp` y aproximarlo a uno de los valores en los nombres de las columnas del dataframe `surface` de acuerdo una regla de asignación
2. Entregar la posición `(vto, mn)` en el dataframe `surface`

Este fue el intento que hice:

```
search(vto, k, sp, surface){
  mn = k/sp
  if (0.75 <= mn & mn < 0.825)
    vl = surface[vto,"80"]
  else if (0.825 <= mn  & mn < 0.875)
    vl = surface[vto,"85"]
  else if (0.875 <= mn  & mn < 0.925)
    vl = surface[vto,"90"]
  else if (0.925 <= mn & mn < 0.96)
    vl = surface[vto,"95"]
  else if (0.96 <= mn  & mn < 0.98)
    vl = surface[vto,"97.5"]
  else if (0.98 <= mn  & mn < 1.01)
    vl = surface[vto,"100"]
  else if (1.01  <= mn  & mn < 1.03)
    vl = surface[vto,"102.5"]
  else if (1.03 <= mn  & mn < 1.07)
    vl = surface[vto,"105"]
  else if (1.07 <= mn  & mn < 1.125)
    vl = surface[vto,"110"]
  else if (1.125 <= mn  & mn < 1.175)
    vl = surface[vto,"115"]  
  else if (1.175 <= mn  & mn < 1.26)
    vl = surface[vto,"120"]
  return(vl) 
}
```

Pero no funcionó... Ustedes me pueden ayudar?

Comment: ¿Qué esperas que pase con coeficientes menores a 0.75 o mayores a 1.25?

Comment: puede imprimir un mensaje como este "Vol function is not defined for this level of mn"

Comment: Una duda más el último intervalo es diferente al resto `mn <= 1.25`, es menor/igual versus menor, ¿efectivamente es así?  por que este criterio conspira contra la posibilidad de hacer una solución más concreta y simple.

Comment: Ya lo edité para que quedara como tu dices, puede ser estrictamente menor, no tiene  mucha importancia realmente...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para simplificar la lógica, puedes definir un vector con los límites para cada intervalo y otro con las columnas que le corresponderían:

```
search <- function(vto, k, sp, surface) {

  columnas <- c("80", "85", "90", "95", "97.5", "100", "102.5", "105", "110", "115", "120")
  intervalos <- c(.75, .825, .875, .925, .96, .98, 1.01, 1.03, 1.07, 1.125, 1.175, 1.25)
  idx <- findInterval(k/sp, intervalos)
  if (idx < 1 | idx > length(intervalos) - 1) 
     stop("Vol function is not defined for this level of mn")
  
  surface[vto, columnas[idx]]
}
```

[`findInterval()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/findInterval) se encarga de ubicar el índice del intervalo en función del valor `k/sp`, lo límites son inclusivos a izquierda y exclusivos a derecha (por esto mi comentario, la última condición no sería `(1.175 <= mn  & mn <= 1.25)` sino `(1.175 <= mn  & mn < 1.25)`. La función fallará de forma controlada si al valor `nm` no le corresponde ningún intervalo.

Ejemplo:

```
> search(2, 1.75, 1, surface)
Error in search(2, 1.75, 1, surface) : 
  Vol function is not defined for this level of mn
> search(2, .99, 1, surface)
[1] 29.33
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Qué buena solución, me sirvió mucho